# Two unrelated tables with match and against functions

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, match

How do I combine two unrelated tables into one SQL select statement request. However, both tables need to have the Match and Against functions for full text search. I'm getting a blank response and when I do a single table SQL match and against request it works fine but not when I do two tables.

Table One: transport - only id is a primary key integer auto_increment but the rest are varchar

```
    +----+---------+-----------+--------------+
    | id | title   | type      | tags         |
    +----+---------+-----------+--------------+
    | 1  | triumph | motorbike | sport, black |
    +----+---------+-----------+--------------+
    | 2  | bmw     | car       | hatchback    |
    +----+---------+-----------+--------------+
```

Table Two: automobile - - only id is a primary key integer auto_increment  but the rest are varchar

```
    +----+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+
    | id | name      | kind      | link       | listed  |
    +----+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+
    | 1  | suzuki    | motorbike | /bike/new/ | green   |
    +----+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+
    | 2  | volkwagan | car       | /car/new/  | limited |
    +----+-----------+-----------+------------+---------+
```

I need it to print out something like this (just a note, not sure how I would need id - perhaps two columns id_automobile and id_transport to  references both above tables)

```
    +----+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
    | id | title     | type      | link       | tags         |
    +----+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
    | 1  | suzuki    | motorbike | /bike/new/ | green        |
    +----+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
    | 2  | triumph   | motorbike |            | sport, black |
    +----+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
    | 3  | bmw       | car       |            | hatchback    |
    +----+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
    | 4  | volkwagan | car       | /car/new/  | limited      |
    +----+-----------+-----------+------------+--------------+
```

My failed attempt:

```
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Link</th>
        <th>Tags</th>
      </tr>

    if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
        $search = $_GET['search'];
    } else {
        $search = '';
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `transport` WHERE MATCH(title, tags) AGAINST('".$search."') CROSS JOIN `automobile` WHERE MATCH(name, listed) AGAINST('".$search."')";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$row["title"]."</td><td>".$row["type"]."</td><td>".$row["link"]."</td><td>".$row["tags"]."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    $conn->close();


    </table>
```

I would appreciate any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `UNION` clause should give you the results that you need.

Just make sure that bost `SELECT`s, combined with `UNION`, have similar column sets. You can use `AS` to define aliases.

Something like this:

```
SELECT title, type, '' AS link, tags
WHERE MATCH(title, tags) AGAINST('...')
FROM transport
UNION
SELECT name AS title, kind AS type, link, listed AS tags
FROM automobile
WHERE MATCH(title, kind) AGAINST('...')
```

Comment: Thank you but would that work with full text search - Match() and Against()? i need that within the statement. Column sets meaning type of columns like varchar or the amount of columns?

Comment: Will do, testing everything.

Comment: One question how could i also reference primary id's, can it create new columns like  id_automobile and id_transport to references both tables? use AS right?

Comment: @Dev Sure, use AS.

Comment: How can I add a column 'table_name' and then it would populate by adding either transport or automobile for each record. Sort of an identifier?

Comment: @Dev Just add 'Transport' AS table_name to the first SELECT, and 'Automobile' AS to the second one.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask you another question? How good is full text search? For instance it can not recognise words like Woman and Women that are similar?  Ive tried both 'IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE' and 'WITH QUERY EXPANSION'  with no luck. Any ideas please?

Comment: @Dev Please post it as a separate question :)